# Pandas pd.infer_freq() function cannot get 14D frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I need the `pd.infer_freq()` function to return a frequency that is measured in days because that is a dependency of a library I am using. It can't return `None` or `2W-SAT`, it needs to be some interval of days. The code below does not produce the desired result.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate fake data
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01', end='2022-12-31', freq='14D')
data = np.random.randn(len(date_rng), 2)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Value1', 'Value2'], index=date_rng)

# Print the DataFrame
print(df)

# Declare the frequency is 14 day
df.index.freq = '14D'

# Infer the frequency
inferred_freq = pd.infer_freq(df.index)
print("Inferred Frequency:", inferred_freq)
```

This returns `2W_SAT`. Is there someway to force the infer_freq function to only return frequencies that are days?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this trick to convert `Week` offset to `Day` offset:

```
from pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets import to_offset, Week, Day

# Suppose you don't have any freq defined
df.index.freq = None

# Convert string like '2W-SAT' to an instance of Week offset
offset = to_offset(pd.infer_freq(df.index))

# Now you can cast a Week offset to a Day offset
df.index.freq = Day(offset.n*7) if isinstance(offset, Week) else offset
```

```
>>> df.index
DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-01', '2022-01-15', '2022-01-29', '2022-02-12',
               '2022-02-26', '2022-03-12', '2022-03-26', '2022-04-09',
               '2022-04-23', '2022-05-07', '2022-05-21', '2022-06-04',
               '2022-06-18', '2022-07-02', '2022-07-16', '2022-07-30',
               '2022-08-13', '2022-08-27', '2022-09-10', '2022-09-24',
               '2022-10-08', '2022-10-22', '2022-11-05', '2022-11-19',
               '2022-12-03', '2022-12-17', '2022-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='14D')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need `pd.infer_freq` to return a different value than what it currently does, then you'll need to patch it. You can then use a context manager to turn this patch on/off.

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from functools import wraps

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

@contextmanager
def monkeywrap(module, f):
    if not hasattr(f, '__wrapped__'):
        raise TypeError(f'`f` must be wrapped. See functools.wraps')
    try:
        setattr(module, f.__qualname__, f)
        yield
    finally:
        setattr(module, f.__qualname__, f.__wrapped__)

@wraps(pd.infer_freq)
def _infer_freq(*args, **kwargs):
    freq_str = _infer_freq.__wrapped__(*args, **kwargs) # call wrapped function
    freq, offset = freq_str.split('-')                  # parse output
    return f'{pd.to_timedelta(freq).days}D'             # return new result

# Generate fake data
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01', end='2022-12-31', freq='14D')
data = np.random.randn(len(date_rng), 2)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Value1', 'Value2'], index=date_rng)


# Infer the frequency
# Infer the frequency
print(f'Before: {pd.infer_freq(df.index) = }')     # = '2W-SAT'
with monkeywrap(pd, _infer_freq):
    print(f'During: {pd.infer_freq(df.index) = }') # = '14D'
print(f'After:  {pd.infer_freq(df.index) = }')     # = '2W-SAT'
```

Note the difference in output between the "Before", "During", and "After" the invocation of the context manager.

In your application you might do something like this:

```py
def some_imported_function():
    x = pd.date_range('2022-01-01', '2022-12-31', freq='14D')
    return pd.infer_freq(x)

with monkeywrap(pd, _infer_freq):
    print(f'During: {some_imported_function() = }')
```